# eventos duplicados en un templete al hacer mousemove sobre un elemento

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo un caso donde tengo que generar un `hover` de un elemento por medio de un templete que ejecuta en todo el **website** las mismas acciones, pero la cuestión es que su duplica por lo mismo de que es llamado de manera dinámica esto en **JavaScript**

Aquí esta el código del templete al que le hago el `hover` es el que tiene la clase `results-saveItem`

```
<span class="Item-Selection">
 <img src="/website-images/icons/btn{{ON}}-love.svg" id="_Botton-Love" class="results-saveItem {{saved}}" title="Add To Lovelist" data-groupnumber="{{groupnumber}}"> 
</span>
```

El código de **jQuery** que hace el `hover` es el siguiente:

```
$(document).on("mousemove",".results-saveItem",function()
{
 var love_green = "/website-images/icons/love-border-green.svg"; $(".results-saveItem").attr("src",love_green); 
});
```

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] para que veamos mejor el problema? Así rápido, tan sólo con el código expuesto no habría motivo para que se duplicara el evento.

Answer (score 2):

En vez de aplicar la modificación sobre todos los elementos que comparten la clase `.results-saveItem`, aplícala sólo sobre el objeto que gatilla el listener:

```
$(document).on("mousemove",".results-saveItem",function() {
   var love_green = "/website-images/icons/love-border-green.svg"; 
   $(this).attr("src", love_green); 
});
```

EDIT: Si  fuese por ejemplo un `<div>` y quisieras cambiarle el background image:

```
$(document).on("mousemove",".results-saveItem",function() {
   var love_green = "url(/website-images/icons/love-border-green.svg)"; 
   $(this).css("background-image", love_green); 
});
```

Comment: Gracias ya esta listo si me funcionó gracias por su aporte

Comment: Y que tendría que hacer si en la imagen dentro del span es un brackground como podría cambiarla si le hago click el selector que tengo seria $(document).on ("mouseenter",".addToCarts",function(){ var cart_green = "/website-images/icons/cart- hover. Svg; /*este selector es el k quiero corregir*/ $(this).attr(" src ").css("brackground-image, cart_green"); "});

Comment: Añadí el caso en que quieras usar background-image

Comment: Gracias también fue de gran ayuda su aporte enserio